# best way to generate sequentual filenames

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate filenames, 
log.txt
log1.txt
log2.txt
etc

```
int filenum = 0;
public static void Maker()
{
  string basename = "log";
  string extention = ".txt";
  string finalname = "log.txt";
  for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(workingDIR + finalname, true))
        {
           // addadder(filenum);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append(base);
            builder.Append(filenum);
            builder.Append(extension);
            finalname = builder.ToString();

        }   } 
}
```

Is there a better way to create these types of files ?
The first file need to have no number in it EI log.txt
thanks

Comment: I dont know why you need to do that, but that is a perfectly valid way to do it (using a for loop I mean)... I would suggest you do not need to use a StringBuilder for such a small concatenation though

Answer (score 4):

You can replace all of this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(base);
builder.Append(filenum);
builder.Append(extension);
finalname = builder.ToString();
```

with this:

```
finalname = string.Format("log{0}.txt", filenum);
```

or with this:

```
finalname = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", basename, filenum, extension);
```

Answer (score 2):

To build the file name you can use string format:

```
finalname = string.Format("log{0}.txt", (i + 1));
```

Then the build the file name you should use Path.Combine which is in the System.IO namespace

```
 using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(workingDir, finalname), true))
 {
```

Comment: `.ToString()` is not necessary :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string basename = "log";
string extention = ".txt";
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(
        workingDir, string.Format("{0}{1:000}{2}" basename, i, extension), true))
    {
        // write file content using writer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
const string basename = "log";
const string extention = ".txt";
IEnumerable<string> fileNames = Enumerable.Range(0, 300).
   Select(index => string.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", basename, index, extension));
```

To generate the sequence of filenames

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
       string fileName = "log.txt";
       int count = 0;
       if (File.Exists(fileName))
       {
           fileName = fileName + "(" + count.ToString() + ").txt";
           count++;
       }
       else
       {
           //Add your logic here
           File.Create(fileName);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Maker()
{
  string basename = "log";
  string extention = ".txt";
  string finalname = "log.txt";
  for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
  {
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(workingDIR + finalname, true))
       {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                finalname = basename + extention;
            }
            else
            {
                finalname = basename + i + extention;
            }
       }
  }
}
```